# Counting duplicate elements in a Java String array

Tags: java, arrays, string, duplicates

I have a String array that has been randomly populated by String elements. I would like to iterate through the array and keep count of how many duplicate elements are found. I have found other answers that simply check if there is a duplicate or the position of a duplicate but not how many duplicates exist in the array.

For example:

```
String [] arrayToCheck = {"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"};
```

The number of duplicates found would be 3 (1 of each string is duplicated).

I've tried many different things but can't seem to come up with code that gives me the correct answer (the number of duplicates in the array) no matter how many duplicates there are.

Here's is what I've tried to no avail:

```
int numDupes = 0;

for (int j = 0; j < arrayToCheck.length; j++) 
     for (int k = j + 1; k < arrayToCheck.length; k++) 
          if (k != j && arrayToCheck[k].equals(arrayToCheck[j])) 
              numDupes++;
```

AND:

```
int numDupes = 0;

for (String someVal : arrayToCheck) {
     for (int i = 0; i < arrayToCheck.length; i++) {
          if (arrayToCheck[i].equals(someVal)) {
              numDupes++;
          }
     }
}
```

AND:

```
int numDupes = 0;

for(int i = 1; i < arrayToCheck.length; i++) {
    if(arrayToCheck[i].equals(arrayToCheck[i-1])) {
       numDupes++;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Where is your code or you want us to code ??

Comment: Do you mean - String [] someArray = "A, B, C, A, B, C"; or String [] someArray = {"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"}

Comment: Well I would have thought, "I've tried many different things...", would have implied that I did in fact try, but I guess you're worried that I'm somehow a paid programmer getting "free" code from you? Anyway, How likely is that versus the fact that I'm a novice Java programmer who is stuck on what is likely a simple problem? I'll try to edit with what I've tried so far. Thanks for setting me and TheLostMind straight though. I was ready to make off with my millions from your finding duplicates in a Java array code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like below. Put it in a map with count as value. Then simply count strings with `count > 1`.

```
    String [] someArray = new String[]{"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"};
    Map<String,Integer> repeatationMap= new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    for(String str : someArray){

        if(repeatationMap.containsKey(str)) {
            repeatationMap.put(str,repeatationMap.get(str) + 1);
        }
        else {
            repeatationMap.put(str, 1);
        }
    }

    int count = 0;
    for(int repatCount : repeatationMap.values()){
        if(repatCount > 1) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of Strings repeated : " + count);
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert it to a set.. Then (length_of_Set - length_of_Array) is your count of duplicate elements.

Note : This will not tell you how many times each element is duplicated or which elements are duplicated.

Comment: please don't give answer to these type of questions where OP doesn't want to do some code for him/herself and asks for well cooked code (**for free**)...(*by the way, I'm not the -1 guy*)

Comment: @AnkitLamba - This isn't "well cooked" code. I am just pointing him to the right direction.

Comment: I'm not saying that your answer is "well-cooked", I'm only saying that the **OP** want a "well-cooked" code.